Azure Devops Build Error - Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Starting to see this on multiple pipelines:
E:\agent\_work\1051\s\contoso.EAC.UI.WebApplication\contoso.EAC.UI.WebApplication.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
E:\agent\_work\1051\s\contoso.EAC.UI.WebApplication\contoso.EAC.UI.WebApplication.csproj : error NU1301:   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
E:\agent\_work\1051\s\contoso.EAC.UI.WebApplication\contoso.EAC.UI.WebApplication.csproj : error NU1301:   Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'HandshakeFailure'.
E:\agent\_work\1051\s\contoso.EAC.UI.WebApplication\contoso.EAC.UI.WebApplication.csproj : error NU1301:   The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.
  Failed to restore E:\agent\_work\1051\s\contoso.EAC.UI.WebApplication\contoso.EAC.UI.WebApplication.csproj (in 6.02 sec).


If this is self-hosted agent, you should try if this VM works for nuget download packages, and make sure SSL or TLS1.2 enable on this VM
